Geometric quantisation: finding leaves of a polarisation
Let $N=\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1$ be a symplectic manifold with symplectic form $\omega=\mathrm{d}\theta\wedge \mathrm{d}\phi$. The prescription of geometric quantisation is to choose a polarisation $P$ to construct the quantum Hilbert space. A polarisation is a choice of Lagrangian subspace $P_z\subset T_z^\mathbb{C}N$ at each $z\in N$ satisfying $[X,Y]\in P\ \ \forall \,X,Y\in P$. The leaves of a polarisation are the maximal connected submanifolds $R\subset N$ such that $T_z^\mathbb{C}R=P_z$. Correct me if I'm wrong, but a polarisation is what a mathematician would call an involutive distribution and the Frobenius theorem provides the leaves of the foliation.

I would like to know, given the polarisation $P_z=\mathrm{span}\{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+a\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\}$, how to find the leaves. The author gives leaves of the form $\{(e^{i\theta_0}e^{it},e^{iat})\in N\ |\ t\in\mathbb{R}\}$, but I have no idea how it is derived (possibly from writing down an ODE, like with integral curves? But not sure what to write down.)

Now I pose the converse: let $N=\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{R}$, the author supposes $P$ to be the purely real polarisation ($P=\overline{P}$) such that the leaves are $\mathbb{S}^1\times\{x\}$. How do I find the polarisation giving rise to this? By the definition I would just find the tangent space of each leaf, which I think would be $\mathrm{span}\{{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}}\}$. Is this correct?


This is not a homework question, it is conceptual understanding that I lack, because I haven't formally studied the theory of distributions and foliations. Any hints to either question would be greatly appreciated.

In general, the community here discourages the ad hoc creation of new tags.  If you believe that a new tag would be of benefit to the community, please discuss it in the Tag Management Thread.
